# Error:null value in entry: destinationDir=null

Tags: android

> Error:null value in entry: destinationDir=null

`Gradle` выдает мне ошибку в самом начале компиляции. Я даже не понял после чего эта ошибка появилась. Помогите пожалуйст куда копать. `Invalidate caches restart` нажимал. Удалил папку `c:\Users\Win7\.gradle\caches\`

> 06-28 10:10:22.099: D/dalvikvm(12396): GC_CONCURRENT freed 951K, 31% free 5342K/7696K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 54ms
>
> 06-28 10:10:22.420: W/GAv4-SVC(12396): Network compressed POST connection error: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to ssl.google-analytics.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 60000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
>
> 06-28 10:10:39.256: I/PlayCommon(13537): [402] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(220): Preparing logs for uploading
>
> 06-28 10:10:39.256: I/PlayCommon(13537): [402] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(224): No file ready to send
>
> 06-28 10:10:47.674: I/PlayCommon(13537): [434] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(220): Preparing logs for uploading
>
> 06-28 10:10:47.674: I/PlayCommon(13537): [434] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(224): No file ready to send
>
> 06-28 10:10:59.996: I/ActivityManager(1782): No longer want com.google.android.partnersetup (pid 13504): empty for 1822s
>
> 06-28 10:11:19.165: D/ConnectivityService(1782): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=100

Android monitor

```
06-28 09:58:27.462 1888-1888/? D/PhoneStatusBar: disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info back home RECENT* clock search >
                                                 
                                                 --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
06-28 09:58:27.482 1782-1798/? V/TAG: bug 7643792: fitSystemWindows([0,38][0,0])
06-28 09:58:27.512 1888-1888/? D/PhoneStatusBar: disable: < expand icons alerts ticker system_info BACK* HOME* RECENT CLOCK* search >
06-28 09:59:47.610 13146-13149/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 597K, 41% free 4612K/7696K, paused 15ms+5ms, total 68ms
06-28 09:59:48.051 1782-1848/? D/ConnectivityService: handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=100
06-28 10:00:19.862 12396-14617/? W/GAv4-SVC: Network compressed POST connection error: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to ssl.google-analytics.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 60000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
06-28 10:00:19.902 12396-12398/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 943K, 31% free 5361K/7696K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 42ms
06-28 10:00:39.150 13537-13561/? I/PlayCommon: [402] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(220): Preparing logs for uploading
06-28 10:00:39.150 13537-13561/? I/PlayCommon: [402] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(224): No file ready to send
06-28 10:00:47.479 13537-13611/? I/PlayCommon: [434] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(220): Preparing logs for uploading
06-28 10:00:47.479 13537-13611/? I/PlayCommon: [434] com.google.android.play.a.g.e(224): No file ready to send
06-28 10:01:38.198 1782-1848/? D/ConnectivityService: handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=100
06-28 10:02:20.389 12396-14619/? W/GAv4-SVC: Network compressed POST connection error: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to ssl.google-analytics.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 60000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
06-28 10:02:25.024 1782-1976/? W/ThrottleService: unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
06-28 10:03:28.346 1782-1848/? D/ConnectivityService: handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=100
```

Не помогло.
Мой Гредл

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.win7.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Мой манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.win7.myfirstapp">

    <!--
     PERMISSION_GROUP PHONE
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>-->

    <!--
     PERMISSION_GROUP CONTACTS
    -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>-->

    <!--
     PERMISSION_GROUP STORAGE
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!--
     PERMISSION_GROUP SENSORS
    -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>-->

    <!--
     PERMISSION_GROUP AUDIO
    -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>-->

    <!--
     PERMISSION_GROUP CALENDAR
    -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>-->

    <!--
     PERMISSION_GROUP CAMERA
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

    <!--
     PERMISSION_GROUP LOCATION
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!--
     PERMISSION_GROUP SMS
    -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>-->

    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD25og60d-PRnAoHqnatHrbCiWF2BvxCx0"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Зачем логи рантайма, если у вас ошибка компиляции? Покажите логи компиляции. И версию gradle в студию.

Answer (score 2):

Англоязычный SO подсказывает удалить папку `.gradle` в корне проекта и пересобрать.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41248713/5479247

Так же гуглится баг в самом Gradle, исправлен в версии 3.3

Comment: Eugene Krivenja Спасибо помогло. Я бы дал плюсик но не могу.

Comment: Главное, что помогло :)